# node-inspector how to start

Tags: node.js, macos, debugging, node-inspector

How do you use node-inspector?  I cannot get it to stop at a breakpoint or step through my code.  I suspect that there is something wrong with the way I am starting node-inspector.  What am I doing wrong?

I will provide the following details:

- Information about the code I am trying to debug, including a github repository.
- Information about my operating system and how I installed node-inspector and Strongloop.
- Information about what I see when I try to debug.

**Code**.  I am toward the end of the Thinkster tutorial:  https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial.  This code stores ‘posts’ in a MongoDB.  A post is a title and a link.  A user can add comments and upvote a post or comment.  When I click on a comment, it should go to another page to display the post and associated comments.  This part was not working. There was an error in the routing.  I wanted to set a breakpoint in views/index.ejs on this line (about line 69):

router.get('/posts/:post', function (req, res, next) {

My code is here:  https://github.com/bessieatrazoyo/f2lapper-news

**OS and Install** I am working on a Mac OSX machine.  Likely, I have Node.js and MongoDB installed correctly, because I can see the website displayed, and I can create a new post.  I installed node-inspector first like this:

sudo su
npm install -g node-inspector

Later on, I read this information:  docs dot strong loop dot com/display/SL/Installing+on+MacOS
and I installed Strongloop like this:

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm install -g strongloop

**What I am trying** To get the application started and to try to debug, I do the following:

In a terminal, I do this:
brew services start mongodb
npm start

In Chrome, I look at this address:  localhost colon 3000/#/home, and I can see my application run.

In a second terminal window, in the same directory where I said npm start, I type this:

slc debug

It opens Chrome at this address:  localhost colon 8080/debug?port=5858  I set a breakpoint in the routes.js file that controls the response to various URLs and set a breakpoint.  Then, I click on Resume Script Execution (looks like a play button), but nothing ever happens.   I expect to get to the breakpoint that I set when I click on comments.  I’ve tried putting the breakpoint right at the beginning of /routes/index.js, but it never gets to the breakpoint.  If I do a refresh in the Chrome browser with the address: localhost colon 8080/debug?port=5858 or localhost colon 3000/#/home, it refreshes as expected, but I still can’t see any information in the debug window.

PS Sorry for all the 'pseudo' links.  I do not have enough reputation points to post links.

Comment: You need to start the node-inspector. and node program in debug mode.